# iOS app gives generic error when edit banned

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, error-message, edit-ban

If a user tries to suggest an edit using the SE iOS app while edit banned, they are shown the generic error "user cannot submit edits to this question".

[image: suggested edit error]

Meanwhile, trying to suggest an edit on the desktop website will give a much more specific error.

[image: more specific edit error]

Is is possible to provide a more specific error message for iOS users who have been edit banned?

Comment: Well I mean, the user *Cannot suggest edits to the question* I think it's good enough

Comment: @RobbieRotten There are many other reasons a user might think they couldn't edit a question. The edit queue could be full, the user may have too many pending edits, the post could have another pending edit...

Comment: oh, I see what you mean now.  I'll undo my down vote if the question is edited